# AJAX opening in a new window instead of returning to page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX request which, once it gets a reponse is going to a blank page with the result instead of going to the success function in the method.

The jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("form.AjaxSubmit").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);

        var url = $form.attr('action');
        var data = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            timeout: 60000,
            tryCount: 0,
            retryLimit: 3,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveUserDetails(SingleUserModel model)
    {
        int UserResult = 1;

        using (var ctx = new DEVUSEntities())
        {
            SqlParameter pUserNum = new SqlParameter("@UserNum", model.UserNum);
            SqlParameter pFirstName = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", model.FirstName);
            SqlParameter pSurname = new SqlParameter("@Surname", model.Surname);
            SqlParameter pJobNum = new SqlParameter("@JobNum", model.JobTitleNum);
            SqlParameter pExt = new SqlParameter("@Extension", model.Ext);
            SqlParameter pLoginId = new SqlParameter("@LoginID", model.UserId);
            SqlParameter pSectionNum = new SqlParameter("@SectionNum", model.SectionId);
            SqlParameter pOldSectionNum = new SqlParameter("@OldSectionNum", model.OldSectionId);
            SqlParameter pOldLoginId = new SqlParameter("@OldLoginId", model.OldUserId);

            UserResult = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update_user_details_u @UserNum, @FirstName, @Surname, @JobNum, @Extension, @LoginID, @SectionNum, @OldSectionNum, @OldLoginId", pUserNum, pFirstName, pSurname, pJobNum, pExt, pLoginId, pSectionNum, pOldSectionNum, pOldLoginId);
        }

        return Json(UserResult);
    }
```

The form is a standard form with knockout bindings.

I have the following scripts being referenced:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

I have put a break, using Firebug to see if it hits the success or error and it doesn't. In-fact it seems to go to the controller and then straight away go the the blank page with the result of the Json.

Anyone able to help me?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As requested, the value of Url.

The form is:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SaveUserDetails", "AJAXUser")" method="post" class="AjaxSubmit" id="userDetailsForm">
```

When I debug it actually doesn't catch the break but if I managed to get it by breaking early and it is /AJAXUser/SaveUserDetails which is fine.

EDIT2: I have noticed on the stored proc the controller is calling it has the following:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK

RETURN -1
```

And -1 is the result being returned. COuld that be the problem?

Edit 3:

Okay if I put in an alert straight after the .ready then on pageload it fires.

I also put an alert after the .submit event and that obviously doesnt fire.

When I click the submit button neither of the alerts fire.

Comment: Can you post the value of `url`?

Comment: try to add async:false ...and also you don't need event.preventDefault(); because return false will prevent from original form submit.

Comment: You don't need the `return false` by the way. Not sure if that is affecting the code though..

Comment: you go to a black page after the alert?

Comment: @Rickdep sounds like the `.preventDefault()` is not actually doing anything, so the success method is never being called..

Comment: The ajax function that you makes is working asynchronously and because you have   timeout: 60000, on success you don't have what you are expecting to have ...so add async:false,and take out .preventDefault().

Comment: I have added the value of Url. 

@Rickdep No before the alert. It doesn't go to success or error. 

Michael Yes that is what I thought. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have added async:false and taken out .preventDefault but I get the same problem.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if the `return false` is screwing up jQuery. I know that using it by itself does a `preventDefault` and a `stopPropagation` but maybe doing both is causing an issue..

Comment: did you try without timeout: 60000?

Comment: You need to have `preventDefault` it should stop the browser from actually 'POSTing'

Comment: Unfortunately taking out return: false didn't help either

Comment: return false will prevent from original form submit.

Comment: Are oyu sure there are no javascript errors? and can you check the for don't post on your blakc page

Comment: @MDDDC yes I tried that too. Same problem

Comment: @Rickdep No Javascript errors. It does a get and a post (WHich is as I would expect.

Comment: Modifying the timeout wont make a difference. That is the time XHR will wait before going to the error callback.

Comment: Are you submitting the form with a normal `<input type="submit"/>` ?

Comment: I have updated with a second edit

Comment: @Lex Eichner Can you try to do an alert before the preventdefault so you are sure the onsubmin it triggerd when you post the form

Comment: @Rickdep Ahah! I put the alert directly infront of the preventDefault and it did not show meaning it is not being triggered.

Comment: @LexEichner, didn't you say above that you can see the event being entered in FireBug?

Comment: @Lex Eichner try to do an alart after ready so you are sure that works and else try do edit $("form.AjaxSubmit") becouse he there should be the problem

Comment: I have updated my question in regards to the alerts

Comment: change return of method in controller to return Json(UserResult,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: @MichaelCoxon When I debug on VS It reaches the break I put in the controller so it is certainly getting that far. But the alert after the .Submit isn't firing.

Comment: @MDDDC same problem I am afraid.

Comment: did you add to return JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet ?

Comment: @LexEichner, It will still go through with the post as you have it defined in your `<form>`. Don't remove this though, it allows the form to be used if the browser does not support JS. I would however suggest to have a way so that non-JS users can still post the form - for standards sake.

Comment: Also, is the JS declared after the form in the HTML? Even via include..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can get, your event is not being entered for some reason (whether it be that the form is AJAX'd in or is created after the jQuery is parsed. To solve both issues I would suggest changing your event declaration to the following

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on("submit", "form.AjaxSubmit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);

        var url = $form.attr('action');
        var data = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            timeout: 60000,
            tryCount: 0,
            retryLimit: 3,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It will make sure that all forms regardless of how they were created will fire the event.

Comment: @MichaelCoxton Hi Michael. That has done it. Could I ask why that has worked when my one failed? The only difference is that it isn't in document.ready?

Comment: This line `$(document).on("submit", "form.AjaxSubmit", function (event) {` causes jQuery to attach the event to the document and not the element. My guess is that your jQuery was being run before the form was created.

Comment: Ahhhhhh I see. Yes that makes sense. Thanks for your help mate. Greatly appreciated. That had me stumped for an hour!

Comment: Ha! It is always the simplest of problems that get us the most stumped :p